# Not running RabbitMQ on Linux, can not find the file xmerl.app

Tags: linux, erlang, rabbitmq, opensuse

I use `OpenSUSE 12.3`
I installed `erlang` and `erlang-otp (R14B04)`

I started RabbitMQ `./rabbitmq-server`

is an error:

```
$:/opt/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_server-3.1.3/sbin # ./rabbitmq-server


BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {error,{"no such file or directory","xmerl.app"}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   ./../var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@testTFOMS.log
   ./../var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@testTFOMS-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{app_utils,load_applications,2},
    {app_utils,load_applications,1},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-1-',0},
    {rabbit,start_it,1},
    {init,start_it,1},
    {init,start_em,1}]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{error,{"no such file or directory","xmerl.app"}}}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I can find the file

```
 $:find / -name 'xmerl.app'
/usr/lib/erlang/lib/xmerl-1.2.10/ebin/xmerl.app
```

where you need to specify it to start the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the rpm package for CentOS and set it using zypper, then start up rabbitMQ

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you start `xmerl` without `rabbitmq`? Just:

   application:start(xmerl).
2. Try:

   code:add_path("/usr/lib/erlang/lib/xmerl-1.2.10/ebin/").

And than:

```
./rabbitmq-server
```